# How to display a text in a component having another inside using Wicket?

Tags: nested, components, wicket

Say we have a component A which has a component B in it and wants to display a text next to it as well:

```
<div wicket:id="componentA" id="A" class=parent">
    <div wicket:id="componentB" id="B" class="child"></div>
    Text
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to display a "Text" inside a componentA having simple WebMarkupContainer in it too.

I have tried to get around this by the following construct:

```
<div id="A" class=parent">
    <div wicket:id="componentB" id="B" class="child"></div>
    <wicket:container wicket:id="text" />
</div>
```

You see that I do not need the outer div to be a wicket component.

But then it fools out the parent / child class structue so that the text is displayed in the incorrect location (for instance below the child div instead of next to it). How to handle such situations in Wicket?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `wicket:id="text"` the only Wicket component here? If not, please add the missing other wicket:ids. Also, which kind of components are at play here? (Panel, Label, etc.) I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Please see my updated question. The only requirements are that the id="B" is a WebMarkupContainer and the id="A" has to have this component and a variable text next to it (so the text must be a part of another component - the question is where to place it).

Comment: Still don't understand your requirement. Can you post waht the final html has to look like?

Comment: Exactly as in the first code snippet. The "Text" is to be generated by wicket dynamically.

Comment: If I understand it correct then your text is coming below component B and you want it side to component B. Try span for component B not div . say <span wicket:id="B"></span>. html div will always push the next component to below.